# Displaying a pound sign in Lynx browser?

Tags: accessibility, lynx

Is there anyway to have a pound sign display correctly using Lynx text only browser?

using ampersand-pound-semicolon it just shows a u with an accent on top.
using £, nothing displays.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you communicating the charset with the content-type?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your html is written in some other charset encoding than what the web server is telling the client. The easiest fix is to add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

to your `<head>` tag. Another approach is to make the web server send the correct header. For instance:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Note that "`utf-8`" is just an example. Replace that with your actual encoding.

Comment: You also need to have Lynx and your terminal correctly configured to display data in the same character set (which needs to include the pound sign).

Comment: And the Content-Type HTTP header is the correct, reliable approach. Meta will be overridden by it.